# iOS - Maximum number of certificates generated

Tags: ios, itunes, itunes-connect

Estoy a punto de publicar una app. Recién obtuve la invitación para el programa de Apple Developer. He leído la documentación, y tengo entendido que lo primero es crear el iOS App IDs. Listo.
Luego, debo de agregar un certificado de producción, pero no me permite.
En la opción de **App Store and Ad Hoc** me aparece ***(Maximum number of certificates generated)***

No consigo comprender cuál sería el flujo para poderla publicar. Los certificados que ya se encuentran agregados, si los descargo, me baja un archivo .cer, pero el que requiero, según entiendo, es el .p12
Luego, se supone que debo de crear un provisioning profile, ese se instala con el certificado que yo debería de crear y subir a la apple developer, ¿no?

Les agradecería si me pudieran orientar. Saludos.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Básicamente puedes tener hasta 2 certificados para firmar código. Con esos certificados puedes crear/firmar perfiles de aprovisionamiento.

Los perfiles de aprovisionamiento pueden ser de desarrollo (para probar en tu teléfono), adhoc (para distribuir a tus beta testers) o del app store (para subir a la tienda).

Para registrar una app en el sitio de Developer, tienes que crear un App ID y asignarle tu Bundle ID. Después crear el provisioning profile (del tipo que quieras) y eso conecta el certificado, el app id y el perfil de aprovisionamiento.

Comment: Entonces puedo utilizar el certificado que ya alguien más en la cuenta ha agregado. ¿Necesitaría nada más que me pase el .p12, instalarlo, luego creo que provisioning profile como mencionas y ese igual lo instalo y desde el Xcode lo asigno?
Muchísimas gracias. Me ha resultado confuso con la documentación del sitio de Apple.

Comment: Efectivamente, tienes que importar el P12 en tu Mac. Recuerda que cada vez que generes un certificado tienes que exportarlo desde tu Mac a un archivo, si no, vas a perder la llave pública si pierdes/borras el Mac. Desde Xcode no ves los certificados pero sí los provisioning profiles, que requieren el certificado correspondiente.